# run Implementation error. it's my coding wrong?

Tags: verilog, vivado

I'm got a error when running Implementation at vivado 2018.2

this is error detail Info:

[Place 30-494] The design is empty
Resolution: Check if opt_design has removed all the leaf cells of your design.  Check whether you have instantiated and connected all of the top level ports.
[Common 17-69] Command failed: Placer could not place all instances

and my codes is following:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module fa_seq(a, b, cin, sum, cout);
    input a, b, cin;
    output reg sum, cout;
    reg t1, t2, t3;
    always
         @(a or b or cin) begin
             sum <= (a ^ b & cin);
             t1 = a & cin;
             t2 = b & cin;
             t3 = a & b;
             cout = (t1 | t2) | t3;
    end
endmodule

module fa_top;
    reg pa, pb, pci;
    wire pco, psum;

    fa_seq uf1(pa, pb, pci, psum, pco);
    initial
        begin: blk_only_once
            reg[3:0] pal;

            for(pal = 0; pal < 8; pal = pal + 1)
                begin
                    {pa,pb,pci} <= pal;
                    #5 $display("pa,pb,pci = %b%b%b",pa,pb,pci,":::pco,psum=%b%b",pco,psum);
                end
        end
endmodule
```

thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check whether you have instantiated and connected all of the top level ports.

It looks like you synthesized your actual design **AND** your test-bench.
The test-bench is the top level module and has no ports so all logic is optimised away.

You should split your design in files which hold the RTL and files which hold the test-bench/simulation code. In Vivado you have to specify what type it is if you 'add a file' here is a screen shot:
[image]

Comment: thx. I'm a new-bird in verilog(Vivado). But I have chosen "Add or create design sources" when add file. and maybe you are right, the top module should have some ports.

Comment: The normal procedure is to put the test-bench in a separate file and use "Add or create simulation sources" for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a latch inferred. Moreover you have used both blocking and non-blocking assignment in the same always block.

```
always
     @(a or b or cin) begin //Not all dependencies are mentioned
         sum <= (a ^ b & cin); //Non-blocking assignment
         t1 = a & cin;
         t2 = b & cin;
         t3 = a & b;
         cout = (t1 | t2) | t3;
end
```

I suggest you to re-write the always block as shown below.

```
always
     @(*) begin
         sum  = (a ^ b & cin);
         t1   = a & cin;
         t2   = b & cin;
         t3   = a & b;
         cout = (t1 | t2) | t3;
end
```

Actually you don't need an always block for the above combinational logic. Simply use assign statements.

```
module fa_seq(a, b, cin, sum, cout);
input a, b, cin;
output sum, cout;
wire t1, t2, t3;

   assign sum = (a ^ b & cin);
   assign  t1 = a & cin;
   assign  t2 = b & cin;
   assign  t3 = a & b;
   assign  cout = (t1 | t2) | t3;

endmodule
```

However an efficient way of writing a full adder code would be :-

```
module fa_seq(a, b, cin, sum, cout);
input a, b, cin;
output sum, cout;

   assign {cout,sum} = (a + b + cin);

 endmodule
```